# Logic error behind converting distance in C#

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, logic

**Application:** I am trying to convert one type of distance to another when the user inputs the data. However, my output for inches to yards and inches to feet is giving me logic errors of 0 instead of the desire calculation. Feet to yards is not giving me any output and yards to yards is doing the same thing. I have been trying to figure it out for 2 hours and can't seem to understand. The syntax is correct and the logic is the same as the other desire output.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Distance_Converter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ConvertButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int distance_to_convert;
            string lengthOption1;
            string lengthOption2;
            int feet = 12; 




            lengthOption1 = FromListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            distance_to_convert = int.Parse(distancetoconvertTextBox.Text);

            if ((FromListBox.SelectedIndex) != 1 && (ToListBox.SelectedIndex) != -1)

                lengthOption1 = FromListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                lengthOption2 = ToListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            {
                switch (lengthOption1)
                {
                    case "Inches":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = distance_to_convert.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            int inches_feet = distance_to_convert / feet;
                            //int feet = 12; 
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = inches_feet.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            int inches_yard = distance_to_convert / 36;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = inches_yard.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            int feet_inches = distance_to_convert * 12;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = feet_inches.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = distance_to_convert.ToString(); ;
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            float  feet_yard = distance_to_convert / 3;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = feet_yard.ToString();
                        }
                        break;

                    case "Yards":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            int Yards_inches = distance_to_convert * 36;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = Yards_inches.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            int Yards_feet = distance_to_convert * 3;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = Yards_feet.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = distance_to_convert.ToString(); ;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        private void Exitbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what value you are entering in distancetoconvertTextBox?

Comment: It should work. In your division use `double` so `/ 36.0` instead of `/ 36`

Comment: Is the line " if ((FromListBox.SelectedIndex) != 1 && (ToListBox.SelectedIndex) != -1)" supposed to have -1 for both, or do you really want to reject if FromListBox has an index of 1?

Comment: @ForeverZer0- Good point, I removed it and it still outputs the logic error. Which is weird because other portions of the code work.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I tried that and it's still giving me the logic errors for certain portions.

Comment: @Hazarath I am inputting whole numbers and using the number 3 as an example input to check if the program works.

Comment: you are storing result to int. so result is fractional. that's why coming as zero. try to give 48 and see the result

Comment: So this code is very messy. Your if block is only going to evaluate your lengthOption1 if it evaluates to true whereas lenghtOption2 will always be evaluated. Was that intended, because from the way the code is written that's not obvious. Your conversions on the other hand are doing integer divisions which will basically round to the nearest integer down so 1/2 will be 0 (because the remainder is 0.5).To solve this you need to use float or double as a type and force at least one value to be treated as a float / double in the division as that will force the compiler to treat is as expected

Comment: @Toni Kostelac. Ideally, I am trying to selection from one list and another to convert from one type of length to another. Most of it is intentional.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. I'm pointing out that you could have a case where you have the "From" list item selected and the "To" not selected and you'd get nothing as the lengthOption2 will be assigned null and your code wouldn't work. i.e. if both items in both lists needs to be selected then they need to be in the same if block which means using { and } to surround those two lines. Which in your code above is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Having int as the datatype for the variables that store the result is causing the issue. If you store the result of a division in an integer variable, it only stores the whole number.

Consider changing the datatype of inches_yard and other variables  to float, decimal or double.

```
                    else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                    {
                        double inches_yard = distance_to_convert / 36;  //changed datatype from int to double here
                        x = inches_yard.ToString();
                    }
```

Comment: G. changing the datatype for that one would indicating changing it for all.

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to do it, but its still giving me the same problem even changing the datatype.

Comment: @ABerrio I have updated my answer with the relevant code

Comment: G. Thank you for this. I appreciate it! What is weird is that i keep changing everything and I still get the same issue. I am doing exactly as you're showing^^^.

Comment: Consider changing the datatype of distance_to_convert to double or change 36 to 36.0 as suggested by @CodingYoshi

Comment: when you divide an integer (distance_to_convert) with another integer (36), the result will be the integer portion (even if the value is stored in a double variable)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comments. fractions are coming as zero as you stored as int .
use this code snippet. you will get non-zero values in result

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Distance_Converter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void ConvertButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int distance_to_convert;
            string lengthOption1;
            string lengthOption2;
            int feet = 12; 
            lengthOption1 = FromListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();    
            distance_to_convert = int.Parse(distancetoconvertTextBox.Text);

            if ((FromListBox.SelectedIndex) != 1 && (ToListBox.SelectedIndex) != -1)

                lengthOption1 = FromListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                lengthOption2 = ToListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            {
                switch (lengthOption1)
                {
                    case "Inches":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = distance_to_convert.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            double inches_feet = (double)distance_to_convert / feet;
                            //int feet = 12; 
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = inches_feet.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            double inches_yard = (double)distance_to_convert / 36;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = inches_yard.ToString();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "Feet":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            double feet_inches = (double)distance_to_convert * 12;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = feet_inches.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = distance_to_convert.ToString(); ;
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            float  feet_yard =(float) distance_to_convert / 3;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = feet_yard.ToString();
                        }
                        break;

                    case "Yards":
                        if (lengthOption2 == "Inches")
                        {
                            double Yards_inches = (double)distance_to_convert * 36;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = Yards_inches.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Feet")
                        {
                            double Yards_feet = (double) distance_to_convert * 3;
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = Yards_feet.ToString();
                        }
                        else if (lengthOption2 == "Yards")
                        {
                            ConvertedDistanceTextBox.Text = distance_to_convert.ToString(); ;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
        private void Exitbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: forcing a double on multiplication is not needed. Multiplication will work fine.

Comment: @Hazarath. I made this exact change and still having the logic errors. I have tried everything possible and even changed to other different data types and even inputted different numbers.

Comment: @ABerrio did you try debugging line by line and see where it is missing?

Comment: @Hararath Chillara. Yes, I did.

Comment: where its coming as zero..at input level or result level?

Comment: @hazarath. result level.